# White Throated Magpie Jay - Costa Rica

Tags: bird-behaviour, bird-watching, jungle

My wife and I have been watching these magpie Jays for a while and I was just wondering what if all would be the purpose of the plume on their heads. It's strange in it's a single strand with a few feathers. The blue jay in North America has a plume on its head as well but it's more complete.

I'm sure the reason is just for attracting the female but was wondering if there was another reason since it seems so specific instead of just brightly colored feathers like other Male birds have.

Comment: The go-to answers for why does any animal have any thing or behave any way are generally one of these three:  Eat, don't get eaten, make more.  I don't believe the plume helps it eat/ find food, and it seems it might actually make it harder not get eaten (to run away or hide).  That leaves the third choice- make more, which you said yourself, "just for attracting the female."